# dart: nested awaits in object creation

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, initialization, dart

The following script waits for `getCategories` to finish and then prints the data:

```
Stream<Category> getCategories() async* {...}

final data = {
  'categories': await getCategories()
    .map((category) => {'id': category.id}).toList()
};

// {categories: [{id: 0}, {id: 1}, {id: 2}]}
print(data);
```

But, what happens if a category contains a list of sections?

```
final data = {
  'categories': await getCategories()
    .map((category) async => {'id': category.id, 'sections': await category.sections
        .map((section) => {'title': section.title}).toList()
    }).toList()
};

// {categories: [Instance of '_Future', Instance of '_Future', Instance of '_Future']}
print(data);
```

In that case, the script prints a list of `Future` instances. How could I elegantly create objects with nested awaits?

Comment: I'm with a problem like yours, how did you handle this?

Comment: I stopped using Dart in the server-side. I think Dart is a great language to build user interfaces, but it isn't the most suitable option for the back-end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Future.wait() is what you're looking for? It will wait for a list of Futures to complete:

https://www.dartlang.org/tutorials/language/futures#waiting-on-multiple-futures-to-complete-using-futurewait

Comment: The link links to this question ;-) otherwise I also think `var results = await Future.wait(data);` is what he needs.